# Jooma Custom Component Router.php not being called

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I'm using Joomla 3.1.

I'm having a strange issue with my router.php file in my component.

I have a basic router.php file, not doing much as yet, before I add my features I need to get it actually working on basic stuff first.

I have a menu item with the component set as the item type.  Viewing the homepage shows the view I created.

For the links, if I use the following:

```
echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_vacations&view=test&cat=123');
```

I get this:

```
http://mysite/en/component/vacations/?view=test&cat=123
```

I do not want the "component/vacations" shown however.  So I've tried this:

```
echo JRoute::_('index.php?view=test&cat=123');
```

And I get:

```
http://mysite/en/?view=test&cat=123
```

Seemingly correct, however the second method never touches my router.php.  This means I cannot alter it to display something like:

```
http://mysite/en/test/123
```

How can I fix it so that the url is parsed through router.php?

Comment: Does the second URL (`http://mysite/en/?view=test&cat=123`) show the desired component's view?

Comment: Yes it does.  I think I may have figured out the problem, if I set a menu item (besides the homepage) to my component then the links work fine.  It is only when it is from the homepage that the links work as mentioned above.  e.g. `http://mysite/en/menualias/` will generate the links correctly when viewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use JRoute to create links to your application always create full query like in first code:

```
echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_vacations&view=test&cat=123');
```

Router will work as router when you actually write routing functions. Without those your rooter will return links using default joomla routing markup (like this `http://mysite/en/component/vacations/?view=test&cat=123`).
Look into code from any joomla component like **com_weblinks**. It will help you to understand whole process. You can find it here: `/components/com_weblinks/router.php`

Comment: Thank you, I still have issues with the multi-language support but your suggestion has helped me sort out the majority of the issues I was experiencing.  I had looked at some of the other included components for joomla but not the weblinks router which is a great example. :)

Comment: Multi-language support will work fine if you implement it like system want you to. Routing is just for translating queries into useful strings. Multi-language works behind and that process. So if you implement multi-language as it should be, router will work also fine. Weblinks is almost ideal component to look into how Joomla components are build. So if you have any problems just reverse engineer it or certain function you have problem with in your component.